# Pandas - Find the lowest value in range defined by certain values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I struggle while finding the lowest value within a range defined by values in other column.  The range is always defined by two similar values in `boo` column (1-1, 2-2), shown also on image below. Values (`boo` column) are not known in advance (*so I cannot make a list and compare them*), because they are calculated in the code few steps earlier.

[image: Ranges explained]

Dataframe example

```py
    foo           boo
15  36.377949      
16  42.489706     1
17  41.223734      
18  32.281779     0
19  22.888312     2   
20  12.847996      
21   6.876954      
22 -23.872935     1    
23 -31.858878         
24 -39.404905     3   
25 -47.724924     2
26 -4.8161051     3
```

The output is preferred as new dataframe column

```py
    foo           boo    min
15  36.377949      
16  42.489706     1
17  41.223734      
18  32.281779     0      
19  22.888312     2   
20  12.847996      
21   6.876954      
22 -23.872935     1      -23
23 -31.858878         
24 -39.404905     3   
25 -47.724924     2      -47
26 -4.8161051     3      -47
```

I know how to solve this using basic `for` loop (and not leveradging from Pandas functions and speed), so I would like to keep this on dataframe/Pandas/Numpy level, if possible.

Is there a way how to do it using Pandas/Numpy? *Any comments, suggestions and help is appreciated!*

---

### EDIT

I have tried to implement both suggested methods (and they work for small data sets!), however the execution time is not good with larger datasets. I use dataframes with **1.5 - 2.5 milions of rows**, which would take "forever" (*according to increase of execution times*).

`function1` is the one using `find_min_in_range` (from Pedro Rocha) and `function2` is using `for` loop (from mozway).

- x axis is number of rows in dataframe
- y axis is execution time in seconds
- I have tested from `10000` to `200000` rows
- while using my "usuall" dataframe, none of given solution finished
- using `func1 adjusted` whole df iteration took 4-5 minutes

[image: func1 vs func2 vs func1 adjusted]

### EDIT2

I've done another round of testing using provided solutions. It seems like there is significant improvement.

Below are test results with more metrics (number of ranges).

- it seems that Pedros Option 1 and Option 3 are the best performers
- number of ranges in our data samples seems to increase linearly
- only Pedros Option 3 was able to finish finding min on our "whole" data sample [in `172` seconds `1725410` rows and `204954` ranges], *but I am unsure whether it will work in our use case - because we are executing script on 1 vCPU machines* - but I am gonna try it ^^
- [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/18IHKoJ6pUV4DAVKcsgZmCdIgpKy8l2zm/view?usp=sharing) the sample with one of the larges number of ranges in our data, if you would like to use our data (can be loaded using [read_parquet()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_parquet.html) method)
- it seems like the `number of ranges` is always less than `25 %` of total `row count`
- ranges are always closed (*range 0 is exception and only not closed range*)

**Lower number of ranges**
[image: lower number of ranges]
**Higher number of ranges**
[image: higher number of ranges]

However I am unable to reproduce Option 2 from Pedro. Code below (copy paste from generator and option 2).

```py
num_rows = 2000000
num_ranges = 10000

foo_values = [random.uniform(-100, 100) for i in range(num_rows)]
boo_values = [i for i in range(num_ranges)]
boo_values.extend([i for i in range(num_ranges)])
a = np.empty(num_rows-len(boo_values))
a[:] = np.nan
boo_values.extend(a)

random.shuffle(boo_values)

df = pd.DataFrame({"foo": foo_values, "boo": boo_values})

df["min"] = np.nan
idx = df[df.groupby('boo').cumcount() == 1].index
df.loc[idx,"min"] = df.loc[idx].apply(lambda row: df.loc[range(*df[df.boo == row["boo"]].index[[0,-1]]+[0,1]),"foo"].min(), axis=1)
```

Error

```py
  File "/.../option2.py", line 96, in <lambda>
    df.loc[idx,"min"] = df.loc[idx].apply(lambda row: df.loc[range(*df[df.boo == row["boo"]].index[[0,-1]]+[0,1]),"foo"].min(), axis=1)
  File "/.../venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 5069, in __getitem__
    result = getitem(key)
IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0
```

*Also I am thinking about closing this question and creating a new one focused on performance enhacements with provided data sample and more precise description.*

### EDIT3

I am sharing the way how I benchmark different approaches.

- using lighter version of [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/18IHKoJ6pUV4DAVKcsgZmCdIgpKy8l2zm/view?usp=sharing) as input data (lower number of ranges - approx. 200k)
- measuring execution time using `timeit`
- copy&paste results form terminal into GSheet and creating chart

```py
from timeit import default_timer as timer
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Skipped loading the dataframe, can be mocked by using read_parquet from given example file

for i in range(10000, 210000, 10000):
  df = input_df[:i].copy()
  start = timer()
  # here is the code of one or more solution/s
  ...
  f['x'] = round(timer() - start, 1)

  times.append(f)

# Print out execution time
for t in times:
  print(t['x'])
```

Comment: What are you using for the benchmarks?

Comment: I will update the question with exact code I use for benchmarks.

Answer (score 1):

This code first finds the index of the occurrences, if the value in the "boo" column is nan or is the first occurrence, returns nan. Else returns the min value in the range.

**Option 1:**

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def find_min_in_range(row):
    idx = df[df.boo == row["boo"]].index
    if row.name == idx[0]:
        return np.nan
    else:
        return df.loc[range(*(idx)+[0,1]),"foo"].min()

df["min"] = np.nan
idx = [df.boo[df.boo == i].index.max() for i in df.boo.dropna().unique()]
df.loc[idx,"min"] = df.loc[idx].apply(find_min_in_range, axis=1)
```

**Option 2:** find idx using `groupby+cumcount`. Also using lambda function. Better performance if you have a lot of open ranges (1 occurrence in "boo" column, like range `0` in the example)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df["min"] = np.nan
idx = df[df.groupby('boo').cumcount() == 1].index
df.loc[idx,"min"] = df.loc[idx].apply(lambda row: df.loc[range(*df[df.boo == row["boo"]].index[[0,-1]]+[0,1]),"foo"].min(), axis=1)
```

**Option 3:** Using OOP + multiprocessing. Improves performance for large datasets

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from threading import Thread
 
class MinFinder():
    def __init__(self,df):
        self.df = df
        self.range_idx = self.get_range_idx()
        self.min_values = {}

    def get_range_idx(self):
        df_tmp = self.df.reset_index().dropna(subset="boo")
        df_tmp.boo = df_tmp.boo.astype(int)
        df_tmp = df_tmp.set_index("boo")
        return df_tmp.groupby(df_tmp.index)["index"].unique().to_dict()

    def find_min_in_range(self,r):
        idx = self.range_idx[int(r)]
        self.min_values[idx.max()] = self.df.loc[range(*df[df.boo == r].index[[0,-1]]+[0,1]),"foo"].min()
    
finder = MinFinder(df)

t = []
for r in df[df.groupby('boo').cumcount() == 1]["boo"].values:
    t.append(Thread(target=finder.find_min_in_range, args=(r,)))
[thread.start() for thread in t]
[thread.join() for thread in t]

df["min"] = np.nan
df.loc[finder.min_values.keys(),"min"] = [v for v in finder.min_values.values()]
```

Output:

|  | foo | boo | min |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 36.3779 | nan | nan |
| 1 | 42.4897 | 1 | nan |
| 2 | 41.2237 | nan | nan |
| 3 | 32.2818 | 0 | nan |
| 4 | 22.8883 | 2 | nan |
| 5 | 12.848 | nan | nan |
| 6 | 6.87695 | nan | nan |
| 7 | -23.8729 | 1 | -23.8729 |
| 8 | -31.8589 | nan | nan |
| 9 | -39.4049 | 3 | nan |
| 10 | -47.7249 | 2 | -47.7249 |
| 11 | -4.81611 | 3 | -47.7249 |

---

**Testing:**

**Option 1 summary:** I've tested the code with 2M rows and 10k ranges and the test finished after `6:40 min`. While for 2M rows and 1k ranges it takes `42.80 segs`.

**Option 3 summary:** I've tested the code with 2M rows and 10k ranges and the test finished after `4:20 min`. While for 2M rows and 1k ranges it takes `31.40 segs`.

Tested using a `MacbookPro,M1PRO,32gb`

**Option 1 results:**

| Rows | Ranges | Time (segs) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 50000 | 100 | 0.13 |
| 150000 | 1100 | 3.70 |
| 250000 | 2100 | 10.20 |
| 350000 | 3100 | 22.00 |
| 450000 | 4100 | 38.00 |
| 550000 | 5100 | 58.20 |
| 650000 | 6100 | 84.00 |
| 750000 | 7100 | 114.50 |
| 850000 | 8100 | 145.16 |
| 950000 | 9100 | 180.70 |
| 2000000 | 10000 | 400.00 |
| 2000000 | 1000 | 42.8 |

**Option 3 results:**

| Rows | Ranges | Time (segs) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 50000 | 100 | 0.22 |
| 150000 | 1100 | 3.92 |
| 250000 | 2100 | 10.68 |
| 350000 | 3100 | 20.44 |
| 450000 | 4100 | 33.45 |
| 550000 | 5100 | 49.26 |
| 650000 | 6100 | 70.19 |
| 750000 | 7100 | 87.79 |
| 850000 | 8100 | 116.37 |
| 950000 | 9100 | 143.00 |
| 2000000 | 10000 | 260.00 |
| 2000000 | 1000 | 31.40 |

Code to create the test df:

```
num_rows = 2000000
num_ranges = 10000

foo_values = [random.uniform(-100, 100) for i in range(num_rows)]
boo_values = [i for i in range(num_ranges)]
boo_values.extend([i for i in range(num_ranges)])
a = np.empty(num_rows-len(boo_values))
a[:] = np.nan
boo_values.extend(a)

random.shuffle(boo_values)

df = pd.DataFrame({"foo": foo_values, "boo": boo_values})
```

Comment: Thanks! Your solutions seems to perform better than other one, however with more than 50k results, the execution time gets really high. I have adjusted the question and added more details. Thanks.

Comment: I've edited my solution to only apply the function once time per group. Please check if the performance time works for your needs and let me know.

Comment: Thansk Pedro, really appreciate! However I am getting the following error after implementing new version `IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0`.

Comment: Could you provide me more information about the error? line for example?
I've tested my code with 2M rows and 10k ranges and finished in 6:40 min using a M1pro 32gb ram MacbookPro

Comment: Sorry. It fails on this line `if row.name == idx[0]:`, however I think the issue migh be the first `0` value in `boo` row or wrong data type (`boo` was set to `str`, in my df).

Comment: Okay, I have tested your given example and it works. So it definitely has to be issue with types or other values in my dataframe. I am gonna look into it. Thanks :)

Comment: OK, I have figured it out :) I made a mistake while replacing `foo` and `boo` with real value names :)

Comment: Great! I've made more testing with this approach so I'll update my answer with more results if you wanna take a look :)

Comment: Do you consider this performance good enough to mark the answer as accepted? What time would you consider acceptable?

Comment: I need to do a little of testing using real data sample - with the more "realistinc" number of ranges, but ideally I need anything lower than 60 seconds. The legacy solution (converting to dict and using for loop) took usually approx. 40 - 80 seconds, but consumed a lot of memory. So maybe it will be accetable to wait more time, but consume less memory.

Do you think it's possible to down the time (approx 10 times) again?

Comment: I can't find a way to reduce the execution time that much. I'll keep looking for it tough. I'll add another possibility to the answer, it doesn't have a significant improvement in performance (it could be if you have a lot of open ranges -> only 1 occurrence in "boo" column) but it's a shorter code. Thank you :)

Comment: I've added a 3rd option using OOP+Multiprocessing

Comment: Thanks. It seems like the OOP version has the best performance. I will try to do a "real use case" testing and maybe consider adding more cpus, if the results will seem promising.
I have also updated question and added more info and benchmarks.

Comment: Performance of the multiprocessing approach could be improved using more CPU’s of course. Also if you are using cloud services like aws to run your analysis you can create a kind of cluster using lambdas functions. Running lot of lambdas that will analyze one range each, boosting a lot the performance. If you consider using something like this and need a hand, it would be my pleasure to help you.

Comment: It was great to help you, you create a really good post. You can [buy me a coffee here](https://www.buymeacoffee.com/rochap). Thank you very much, is very nice of you.

Comment: Thanks Pedro, I know how difficult it can be to understand the questions here, so I am trying to do my best.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot fully vectorize this as the rows are overlapping, but you can limit the loop to the unique values in `boo`:

```
for v in df['boo'].dropna().unique():
    m = df['boo'].eq(v)
    s = df.loc[m.cummax() & m[::-1].cummax(), 'foo']
    if len(s)>1:
        df.loc[s.index[-1], 'min'] = s.min()
print(df)
```

Output:

```
          foo  boo        min
15  36.377949  NaN        NaN
16  42.489706  1.0        NaN
17  41.223734  NaN        NaN
18  32.281779  0.0        NaN
19  22.888312  2.0        NaN
20  12.847996  NaN        NaN
21   6.876954  NaN        NaN
22 -23.872935  1.0 -23.872935
23 -31.858878  NaN        NaN
24 -39.404905  3.0        NaN
25 -47.724924  2.0 -47.724924
26  -4.816105  3.0 -47.724924
```

Comment: Thanks! Your solutions seems to perform better than other one, however with more than 50k results, the execution time gets really high. I have adjusted the question and added more details. Thanks.

Comment: added an approach inspired from @mozway's answer which is vectorized. would be great if you could benchmark?

Comment: I did benchmark this solution and included in the question as edit.

Answer (score 1):

#### Vectorized solution with pandas

Here is a vectorized way of doing this (inspired from @Mozway's method of using `cummax()`). Please find the details in the comments. However, I have not benchmarked it, so not sure if a specific step here might be too costly -

```
import pandas as pd

#Create the sample dataset
vals = {'foo': [36.377949, 42.489706, 41.223734, 32.281779, 22.888312, 12.847996, 6.876954, -23.872935, -31.858878, -39.404905, -47.724924, -4.8161051], 
        'boo': [np.nan, 1.0, np.nan, 0.0, 2.0, np.nan, np.nan, 1.0, np.nan, 3.0, 2.0, 3.0]}
df = pd.DataFrame(vals)

#Create ranges for computation
g = pd.get_dummies(df['boo'])                #separate columns for each unique value 0,1,2,3...
m = g.cummax() & g[::-1].cummax()            #draw a range of 1s from first to second occurance
g = m.where(m.eq(1))                         #get elements where vals are 1 (Thanks Mozway for this fix!)
s = g.multiply(df['foo'],0).min()            #multiply elementwise the foo colums with 0s and 1s & get min

#Remove column sums that dont have a range (like 0)
c = g.sum()>1                                #check if sum of g was > 1
s = s[c[c].index]                            #filter s by only those indexes (removes 0)

#Attaching the min values back
d = g[::-1].idxmax()                         #find index of last occurance of each value                    
df['min'] = np.nan                           #create a new column with nan values
df.loc[d[s.index], 'min'] = s.tolist()       #append the min values to these indexes in the min col
df
```

```
          foo  boo        min
0   36.377949  NaN        NaN
1   42.489706  1.0        NaN
2   41.223734  NaN        NaN
3   32.281779  0.0        NaN
4   22.888312  2.0        NaN
5   12.847996  NaN        NaN
6    6.876954  NaN        NaN
7  -23.872935  1.0 -23.872935
8  -31.858878  NaN        NaN
9  -39.404905  3.0        NaN
10 -47.724924  2.0 -47.724924
11  -4.816105  3.0 -47.724924
```

---

### Benchmarks

Got a bit inspired with @PedroRocha's benchmarking and decided to add a `perfplot` for the same. Here is reference code to replicate the same. Was unable to test all functions and at higher values of params it was taking insanely long, so skipped those iterations!

```
import random
import perfplot
import pandas as pd

#Function to generate dataframes (Courtsey Pedro Rocha)
def create_data(num_rows, num_ranges):
    foo_values = [random.uniform(-100, 100) for i in range(num_rows)]
    boo_values = [i for i in range(num_ranges)]
    boo_values.extend([i for i in range(num_ranges)])
    a = np.empty(num_rows-len(boo_values))
    a[:] = np.nan
    boo_values.extend(a)

    random.shuffle(boo_values)

    df = pd.DataFrame({"foo": foo_values, "boo": boo_values})
    return df

#Mozway's clean solution (which was the inspiration for my method)
def method1(df):
    for v in df['boo'].dropna().unique():
        m = df['boo'].eq(v)
        s = df.loc[m.cummax() & m[::-1].cummax(), 'foo']
        if len(s)>1:
            df.loc[s.index[-1], 'min'] = s.min()
    return df

#Akshay's solution (aimed at vectorizing using pandas)
def method2(df):
    #Create ranges for computation
    g = pd.get_dummies(df['boo'])                #separate columns for each unique value 0,1,2,3...
    m = g.cummax() & g[::-1].cummax()            #draw a range of 1s from first to second occurance
    g = m.where(m.eq(1))                         #get elements where vals are 1 (Thanks Mozway for this fix!)
    s = g.multiply(df['foo'],0).min()            #multiply elementwise the foo colums with 0s and 1s & get min

    #Remove column sums that dont have a range (like 0)
    c = g.sum()>1                                #check if sum of g was > 1
    s = s[c[c].index]                            #filter s by only those indexes (removes 0)

    #Attaching the min values back
    d = g[::-1].idxmax()                         #find index of last occurance of each value                    
    df['min'] = np.nan                           #create a new column with nan values
    df.loc[d[s.index], 'min'] = s.tolist()       #append the min values to these indexes in the min col
    return df


############################ BENCHMARKS ############################

#PARAMETERS DICT FOR DATA CREATION
params = dict(enumerate(zip(range(1000,500000,5000),
                            range(10,1010,10))))

#n: (rows, ranges)
#0: (1000, 10),
#1: (6000, 20),
#2: (11000, 30),
#3: (16000, 40),
# .........
#96: (481000, 970),
#97: (486000, 980),
#98: (491000, 990),
#99: (496000, 1000)


#PERFPOLT COMPARING METHODS (Was unable to run some methods)
perfplot.show(
    setup = lambda n: create_data(params[n][0], params[n][1]),
    kernels = [method1, method2],
    labels = ["method1","method2"],
    n_range= [i for i in range(0,100)],
    xlabel="n -> params[n] -> (rows, ranges)", 
    equality_check=None
)
```

[image]

Comment: Quick fix of a flaw that would give incorrect results if the min is > 0 (feel free to revert)

Comment: thanks for catching that @mozway and adding a fix. editing to add some of the comments back.

Comment: Oops sorry, was editing from my phone ;)

Comment: I've tested you code with 2M rows and 5k ranges and the test finished after 8:30 mins. Just in case the PO don't benchmark your answer you could have an idea. In my answer you can find a code to create a test dataframe, feel free to use it.

Comment: Thanks for you effort. It seems like your solution has a moderate performance. You can test it using data sample provided in the question.

Comment: Thats very kind of you @FN_! glad this helped. Please visit my [SO profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4755954/akshay-sehgal?tab=profile) and in the about section, press Read More. You should find the link at the end :) Cheers!